# vb.net background of form registered as a button when clicked

Tags: vb.net

I have created a system in vb.net that allows you to click buttons and it will change colour accordingly. It uses code that will be used for each button without referencing each button individually.

```
Dim btn As Button = Nothing  
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls  
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then  
       btn = DirectCast(ctrl, Button)  
       AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.btn_Click  
    End   
Next
```

This works correctly for the buttons, however when you miss-click and click the background of the form it registers the background as a button and breaks the system.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: That mishap is not caused by the code you posted.  We can't see the rest of it so it will just be blind guessing.  Search for "Handles" and "AddHandler".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[Me.Controls.OfType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** function which will return a collection with the Controls of the specified Type:

```
Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)().ToList.
   ForEach(Sub(bt As Button) AddHandler bt.Click, AddressOf Me.btn_Click)
```

Comment: This still throws the same problem when you click the background of the form. It's seeing the background as a button.

Comment: The problem is in other part of the source-code that you are missing, in your `For` loop as in the `ForEach` I shown only iterate Buttons, there is no chance to cause a problem like the problem you described, please revise the `btn_Click` handler to ensure that you are not handling the form `Click` event, or try to update your question to add the relevant code to find where the issue is caused. Sorry for my bad English.